# Apply different color shades to different words according to their weight in wordcloud python library

Tags: python, colormap, word-cloud

I am creating word clouds using the wordcloud python library https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/tree/master/wordcloud
It seems that the color for each word is chosen from a colormap, but applied randomly, e.g. not sequentially where the word/ngram with a bigger weight in the text gets a brighter (or anyway higher to one end of the colormap) color.

I am wondering if there is a way to apply sequential coloring? I tried recoloring using a custom colormap, but the order is still random.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

def create_colormap(rgb_color=(45, 132, 200)):
    N = 256
    color = np.ones((N, 4))
    color[:, 0] = np.linspace(rgb_color[0]/256, 1, N) # R = 45
    color[:, 1] = np.linspace(rgb_color[1]/256, 1, N) # G = 132
    color[:, 2] = np.linspace(rgb_color[2]/256, 1, N)  # B = 200
    cmap = ListedColormap(color)
    return cmap

cmap = create_colormap()
text = "square"
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", repeat=True).generate(text)
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(wc.recolor(colormap=cmap), interpolation="bilinear")
plt.show()
```